# Comparing document fields

Tags: mongodb, search, nosql

Let's say I have this document structure:

```
{
    "user": "John Doe",
    "data": [1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3],
    "data_version": 1
}
```

Can I query by `data` field in such a way so I could match all documents that match at least `N` values inside the array, at the same position?

So for example, in those `data` fields:

```
1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5
2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5
1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2
5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3
```

Searching for

```
1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3
```

with `N` minimum limit being 3, I'd get the 1st and 3rd document, but raising `N` to 4, I'd get only the 3rd document.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have a standard way of doing this ad-hoc. You probably could build a MapReduce that does it for specific arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over your collection. Something similar to the following should work:

```
var N = 3;
var query = [1,3,3,1,5,4,3];
db.users.find().forEach(function(entry) { 
    var similarity = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < entry.data.length; i++) {
        if (entry.data[i] === query[i]) { similarity++; }
    }
    if (similarity > N) { print(entry); }
});
```

Does this help?

Comment: I'd like to avoid that at it requires comparing each value from each field and I'm going to have *a lot* of data, anyways, if I can't find anything else I'll do it this way :)

Comment: well obviously you need to compare at least N values for each document to find if the similarity is as you required. You can exit the for loop once you have found at least N coinciding values, or if the coinciding values plus the remaining comparisons is less than N.

Comment: You could also create an index on the data field. Then query that index such that it contains at least one item in your query. This way you can reduce the amount of documents you need to compare in depth.

Comment: That's a good idea, but won't help me much in practice as I'll have around 100 values per data field, the min value being 1 and the max value 8, there's a really high chance I'll get everything as "possible match with at least 1 value"

Comment: how long is your query? Is it 7 as in the example? Then you could query document ids for each element in your query supported by an index on data, then take the list of documents that are in the intersection of at least K = N of these sets. If an element appears more than once in your query, then you would need to adjust K accordingly.

Comment: No, it's around 80, buy it could grow a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in the query language itself, there is no construct for "match N out of M".  I can't think of a way to do this with a different data model, either.  I actually doubt there's something like that in any query language, or is there?

I think you'd be left doing the matching inside your application.

Comment: I know it's a hard one and I certainly can't think of a way to get it done on the side of the database.